# Can't install ASP.NET Core SDK on Mac

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm trying to install the ASP.NET Core 2.0 API on my MacBook Pro.

I've downloaded both `dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-osx-x64.pkg` and `dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-osx-gs-x64.pkg` and when I try to launch either of them an installer dialog is displayued that just reads:

> Verifying "dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-osx-x64.pkg"

or

> Verifying "dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-osx-gs-x64.pkg"

but nothing further happens.

I am running OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and have all of the latest updates for Visual Studio installed.

I can't locate any further information or instructions for installation. Please help.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote with no explanation. That's quite helpful.

Comment: Sure. That's reasonable. LOL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/macos-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x:

> .NET Core 2.x is supported on the following versions of macOS: macOS
>   10.12 "Sierra" and later versions

Looks like it might be time to upgrade to Sierra. That represents a change from the 1.1 requirements, which supported El Capitan.

FWIW I'm running Sierra on a mid-2012 MacBook Pro with 8GB of RAM and it performs just fine.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that wasn't an automatic update. (I am pretty much a Mac nOOb). I thought since I had no updates pending I had the latest. I'm installing right now and will accept this answer as soon as I verify it works.

Comment: Slightly tangential to the original question, but OS X updates are automatic within a major release (e.g. 10.11.x) but you need to opt-in for major releases (e.g. 10.10.x to 10.11.0)